# What is the level of effort for this fish tank?

Tags: aquarium, saltwater, maintenance

[image: I want this fish tank]

One a scale of 1 to 10 (10 being metaphysically impossible) what is the level of effort to start and maintain a salt water tank with coral and fish (like the picture) for an amature?

I currently have a 10gal fresh water tank with tetras.

Secondary question: Can a fresh water version be created?